# Statically linked executable requires dll

Tags: c++, qt, linker

I am building an executable with only static libraries, but when I try to run the executable I get an error for missing dlls.

Here is my linker command:

```
g++  -mwindows -static -LC:\Qt\6.2.2\mingw_64\lib -o out/TlvTool  out/Src/Main.o  out/Src/MainWindow/MainWindow.o  out/Src/TlvParserWindow/TlvParserWindiw.o  out/Src/TlvParser/TlvParser.o  out/Src/MainWindow/MainWindow.moc.o  out/Src/TlvParserWindow/TlvParserWindow.moc.o  C:\Qt\6.2.2\mingw_64\lib\libQt6Core.a C:\Qt\6.2.2\mingw_64\lib\libQt6Gui.a C:\Qt\6.2.2\mingw_64\lib\libQt6Widgets.a
```

I even added `-static` to disable dlls, also specified the full path to the libraries to make sure it uses static libraries..

Comment: Can you use something like Dependency Walker (or even `ldd`, not sure if it works with MinGW) to find out which DLLs are supposedly missing?

Comment: With Dependency Walker I see  - QT6CORE.DLL, QT6WIDGETS.DLL, KERNEL32.DLL and MSVCRT.DLL.

Comment: All of your component libraries also need to be built statically.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've seen this page:

[Static Qt builds on Windows](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW)

It's good but there are (or at least were) some problems. Here are my notes on getting it to work:

[script errata](https://forum.qt.io/topic/83446/building-a-monolithic-standalone-program/20)

Good luck...

PS: if image size is at all a concern, make sure you read this:

[Qt static image sizes](https://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW#When_to_use_a_Static_Qt_build)